# Run Luigi task that depends on another task

Tags: apache-spark, luigi, hail

I have one task `SeqrMTToESTask` that depends on another one called `SeqrVCFToMTTask`. You can see the full code here:

https://github.com/macarthur-lab/hail-elasticsearch-pipelines/blob/master/luigi_pipeline/seqr_loading.py

Now, I ran the first task separately in the terminal and generated the output file - `sample.mt`. When I launch the second task - `SeqrMTToESTask` I would expect it to check the output of the first task - `sample.mt` and if it is present, take the file and go ahead, but it is not what is happening. Instead of that I am getting the error that signifies that certain parameters to the first task are missing, e.g.:

> luigi.parameter.MissingParameterException: SeqrVCFToMTTask[args=(),
>   kwargs={}]: requires the 'source_paths' parameter to be set

The full command that I use to run the second task is:

```
python -u gcloud_dataproc/submit.py --cpu-limit 4 --num-executors 1 --hail-version 0.2 
--run-locally luigi_pipeline/seqr_loading.py SeqrMTToESTask --local-scheduler 
--dest-file hdfs://.../seqr-loading-test/_SUCCESS_TO_ES --source-path hdfs://.../seqr-loading-test/sample.mt 
--spark-home $SPARK_HOME --es-host cp-nodedev1 --es-port 7890 --es-index sample_luigi
```

So, my question here is the following: how I should run `luigi` task with spark (`gcloud_dataproc/submit.py` just constructs the command that uses `spark-submit`) that depends on other task with its own required parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the right way to go was to just use luigi config file (in my case `seqr-loading-local-GRCh37.cfg`) file where we specify all of the parameters for all of the tasks. So, after specifying all of the parameters for the tasks I was able to run it in the following way:

```
LUIGI_CONFIG_PATH=luigi_pipeline/configs/seqr-loading-local-GRCh37.cfg python 
-u gcloud_dataproc/submit.py --cpu-limit 4 --num-executors 1 --hail-version 0.2 
--run-locally luigi_pipeline/seqr_loading.py SeqrMTToESTask --local-scheduler --spark-home $SPARK_HOME
```